# Edit whitespace in text file

Tags: powershell-2.0

so here is the problem. User inputs string under 11 letters, then text file is opened and "Foo" is replaced with user given string, but the indentation will remain same. let's say I have this data in my text file below.

```
Foo        bar
Foo        bar
Foo        bar
```

Now user inputs "bigdog" and "Foo" will be replaced with it, indentation of text file must remain same, see below.

```
bigdog     bar
bigdog     bar
bigdog     bar
```

How can I accomplish that? so far my code looks like this:

```psh
$name = Read-Host 'write 10 letter string'
(Get-Content file.txt) |
  Foreach-Object {$_ -replace 'Foo        ',$name.PadRight(11, ' ')} |
  Out-File file.txt
```

But simply adding spaces to 'Foo' does not cut it, so any suggestions?

Comment: "But simply adding spaces to 'Foo' does not cut it" - can you explain what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [format operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kathykam/archive/2006/03/29/564426.aspx) (`-f`) for padding and aligning text:

```
$newstring = '{0,10}' -f $name
(Get-Content 'file.txt') |
  ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '^Foo       ', $newstring } |
  Out-File 'file.txt'
```

I'd recommend anchoring the search expression (`^` matches the beginning of a string) unless you want to replace it anywhere in the string. Also, you could condense the expression to `^Foo {7}` (a number in curly brackets matches the expression preceeding it the given number of times, i.e.  `{7}` matches 7 spaces).